# How use ANN in Weka?

Tags: neural-network, weka

When I run Weka and I see all classifiers, I don't see neural networks classifiers. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it in Functions->MultilayerPerception

From the command line:

```
java -cp '.:/usr/share/weka/lib/weka.jar' \
weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -t yourfile.arff
```